# PHP/HTML5 Live audio streaming

Tags: php, sockets, audio-streaming, audio-recording

I would like to stream a live audio (a person is speaking into microphone) and then the audio has to stream over the network to playback on other users browser. I have use PHP, HTML, JavaScript, jQuery or AJAX.

Comment: Since anyone else hasn't, I'll ask: what have you tried? And what is your question actually?

Comment: @Nikola Thanks Nikola, in simple words I have to stream live audio from browser to browser.

Comment: Please have a look at this http://www.appunitz.com/stream-audio-using-php/

Answer (score 0):

I know a way of doing it in flash:

```
var radioStream:String='http://stream.fm1079.co.uk:8000/stream';//my local radio station

function openStream(stream){
var s:Sound = new Sound();
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(stream);
var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(500, true);
s.load(req, context);
s.play();
}//end of function

openStream(radioStream);
```

That will stream any stream URL.

Comment: Thanks navnav, I am trying to find a solution where client will feed the audio to server and server again broadcast audio to other clients. Or through a websocket where we can do it through P2P connections.

Comment: Ah, right. Well you should take a look at the Flash Media Server. http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-media-server-family.html